# How to handle data before delete from model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have the following method:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {

        $id = \JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        $offer = Offer::findOrFail($id);
        $offer->delete();

        return response()->json(["offer" => $offer]);
    }
```

How handle data before deleting? I need to check if user has permit to delete data or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `authenticate()` method, the user model is retrieved so it means the `id` you have is not an id but a `User`. Have you checked [the documentation of JWT](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki) Because first and foremost you have to retrieve the user and this is sufficient:

```
 $user = \JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
```

Then if you have a field for example in your `users` table to tell if the user have the right say `admin` which can be 1 or 0 then you can do the following:

```
if($user->admin == 1)
{
    $offer = Offer::findOrFail(1); //say id
    $offer->delete();

    return response()->json(["offer" => $offer]);
}

return response()->json(['error' => 'you dont have the right to delete this'], 403);
```

Just a little scratch on the idea, but my best advice is to do some searches on how JWT is implemented, I am pretty sure you will find tons of them online.

Comment: Can I use middleware for this?

Comment: Sure you can use middleware to do this. So attempt to authenticate in the middleware and if it succeed then this destroy() function in the controller can get executed. Do you mean I should give example on how this possible could be done?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the Model's delete event:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1122

and [handle](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/events#queued-event-handlers) it.

This will guarantee that if you use the delete method on a model, you always check permissions.